# WebdriverIO commands cannot resize browser window in Chromium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, webdriver-io

I am writing **CoffeeScript** tests using **Webdriver.io** and **mocha**. The code is processed using the CoffeeScript compiler.

I want to set the size of the browser window using the function

```
browser.setWindowSize(a, b)
```

If I do this in Firefox, then the size changes. However, Cromium cannot resize the browser window using this command.

I found a few more commands that should change the size of the browser window:

```
browser.setViewportSize({width:a, height:b})
browser.windowHandleSize(a, b)
browser.windowHandleSize({width:a, height:b})
```

However, the execution of these commands fails:

```
'browser.setViewportSize is not a function'
```

How can I resize the browser window in Chromium?

Comment: Is there a property in the WebDriver config?

Comment: The property "browser.setWindowSize"  is in the WebDriver config.
https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/setWindowSize.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of webdriverIO you are using, but from v5, setViewportSize command does not exist anymore. Please use [setWindowRect](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver.html#setwindowrect)

Usage

```
browser.setWindowRect(x, y, width, height)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I tried using this function in every possible way (https://nightwatchjs.org/api/setWindowRect.html), but in all cases I get an error **browser.setWindowRect is not a function**

Comment: Well the function is correct, check here https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#set-window-rect . There might be some other problem with the code, can you share the code snippet please ?

Comment: browser.url('url_address')
browser.setWindowRect(0, 0, 2048, 1536)

Comment: browser.url('url_address')
browser.setWindowRect({width: 2048, height: 1536})

Comment: Can you please also share the js file using this https://gist.github.com/?